# Regex matching digit and letters or only digits

Tags: regex

I'm stuck trying to code a regex which match with those conditions:

- string with more than 9 digits
- string with more than 9 digits and letters

I can't figure out how to write my regex saying to it: digit or digit and letters can match but not letters.

**Those string should match:**

- *12345678987654567*
- *jhsjd4567hsqdgqsgh456786576567kj*
- *9l8j9n9k0n9n8n*

**Those string should not match:**

- *loremipsum*
- *a1*
- *12567*

My regex so far: `/(?:\w){9,}/`

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: At this point, you are better off using logic of a programming language

Comment: `(?:\w){9,}` is equal to `\w{9,}` and it matches nine or more digits, letters, or underscores/connector punctuation. You might want to use a lookahead like `(?=\w{0,8}[0-9])` at the start, `(?=\w{0,8}[0-9])\w{9,}` or `\b(?=\w{0,8}[0-9])\w{9,}\b` if you need to match within word boundaries. Please add clarification as to what boundaries you need to match these strings in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your requirements as: match a string of more than nine characters which contains either digits only or digits and letters only.

```js
const tests = [
  '12345678987654567',
  'jhsjd4567hsqdgqsgh456786576567kj',
  '9l8j9n9k0n9n8n',
  'loremipsum',
  'a1',
  '12567',
];

for (const t of tests) {
  console.log(t.padEnd(35) +
    /^(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{10,}$/i.test(t)
  )
}
```

The positive lookahead `(?=.*\d)` ensures that there is at least one digit in the string.

Remove the `i` flag if you want to match only lower-case letters.

Answer (score 2):

Using `\w` can match both letters and digits, so using `(?:\w){9,}`, which can be written as `\w{9,}` can also match only letters or only underscores.

Reading the requirements, you can match 9 or more times a letter or a digit and make sure that the string does not contain only letters using a negative lookahead if that is supported.

If you want to match *more than 9*, you can use `{10,}` as the quantifier.

```
^(?![a-zA-Z]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,}$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![a-zA-Z]+$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only characters a-z A-Z in the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,}` Match 9 or more times chars a-z A-Z or a digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J3Fx0R/1)

Or using word boundaries:

```
\b(?![a-zA-Z]+\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,}\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iCfuDo/1)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work

```
/([a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*){9,}/
```

Comment: This wouldn't match `'9l8j9n9k0n9n8n'`, as your regex requires there to be at least nine digits. Also, the question states "more than 9", so `{9,}` should be `{10,}`.